# UITableView in UIStackView - smooth expand and collapse animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uistackview, uianimation

I am trying to implement a table view that allows the user to "show more" rows to toggle the full number of rows or a smaller number of rows. I have all the data upfront when the view is loaded, so I do not need to fetch any extra data.

I am able to get it working, but the problem I am having is that my table view does not smoothly animate when expanding or collapsing. What happens is that if the "show more" action is triggered, the size of the table is updated all at once to the full height of the table with all the data in it. Then the rows will animate.

Likewise when hiding rows, the table height will shrink all at once to the end height and then the rows will animate.

Here is a picture of what is happening. It just "jumps" to the full height and then it animates the rows. But what I would like to happen would be for it to smoothly expand the height of the table unveiling the data as it smoothly expands downward. I would like the opposite, where it smoothly slides upward when pressing "show less".

[image]

The way my app is laid out is as follows:

- `UIScrollView`

  - `UIStackView`

    - `UIViewController`
    - `UIViewController`
    - `UITableView`  <-- the section I am working on here
    - `UIView`
    - ...

Basically, I have a scrollable list of sections of different data. Some sections are tables, some are just ad-hoc views arranged with AutoLayout, others have collection views or page view controllers or other types of views.

But this section is represented by the UITableView in the previous list.

```
#import "MyTableView.h"
#import "MyAutosizingTableView.h"

@interface MyTableView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyAutosizingTableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MyTableView

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    [self.titleLabel setText:@"Details"];
    self.numberOfRows = 3;
    [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    [self addSubview:self.tableView];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.titleLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor],
        [self.titleLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.titleLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor],
        
        [self.tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor],
        [self.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor multiplier:1.0f],
        [self.tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor],
        [self.tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor],
        [self.tableView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.widthAnchor]
    ]];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!self->_tableView) {
        self->_tableView = [[MyAutosizingTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self->_tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self->_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self->_tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        self->_tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self->_tableView.delegate = self;
        self->_tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self->_tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"dataCell"];
    }
    return self->_tableView;
}

- (UILabel *)titleLabel {
    if (!self->_titleLabel) {
        self->_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self->_titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self->_titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self->_titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showMore)];
        [self->_titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    return self->_titleLabel;
}

- (void)showMore {
    if (self.numberOfRows == 0) {
        self.numberOfRows = 3;
    } else {
        self.numberOfRows = 0;
    }
    
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (void)setData:(NSArray<NSString *> *)data {
    self->_data = data;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    //this has no effect unless the view is already in the view hierarchy
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.numberOfRows <= 0) {
        return self.data.count;
    }
    return MIN(self.data.count, self.numberOfRows);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *data = self.data[indexPath.row];
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.data = data;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have a UITableView subclass that I used in the previous code. The reason I have the table view subclass is to get the table to resize when the content changes. If anyone knows a better way to do this without the subclass, I would be very interested in learning that too.

```
#import "MyAutosizingTableView.h"

@implementation MyAutosizingTableView

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return self.contentSize;
}

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get smooth expansion animations? I would really like the table to expand smoothly and reveal the data that is in the new rows.

---

## Update - a high level overview of what I am trying to do

Here I am going to try to describe what it is I am trying to accomplish and how I am going about it, so if anyone has any alternative approaches or improvements for laying this out, I would be very open to suggestions. Thank you in advance for reading this.

So I am working on a view controller that displays data about a product, imagine a car for example. The view controller has different sections responsible for displaying different data. For example, the first section displays pictures of the item and for this section, I am using a UIPageView that displays basically a carousel of product images.

Another section displays options about the current product. For example, someone might choose a different color for the car or different wheels. For this section, I am using a table view to display the list of available attributes, where each attribute is in a different section of the table. Upon pressing the section header, the table view adds a row that displays the available options for that attribute. For instance, assume the car has different colors available (red, green, blue, and yellow). Upon pressing the section header, the table view adds a row and animates that in (using the technique discussed in chapter 8 of "Programming iOS 12"). The row that is shown then contains a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally allowing the user to choose between the colors (or wheel options or whatever attribute is being changed).

Another section displays what other customers have said about this product. For example, if someone leaves a writeup on the car, then that would go in this section. This section is has a table showing how the product fares across different criteria. Using the car example still, it might have a row for comfort and another for gas mileage and another for performance and so on. Then there is also a horizontal UICollectionView displaying the write ups about the product.

Yet another section is a list of attributes for the product. For example, with the car it might show engine size on the left and V12 on the right.

And there are other sections as well, but then to tie them all together I have a scroll view with a vertical UIStackView inside it. And this is what I am really curious about. What is the best way to display or layout all these sections? Is a stack view the way to go or should I use a table view or should I just have a scroll view with these views hooked together just using AutoLayout directly or is there some better way to do it than all of these?

One thing that is very important is that each section can be different sizes between products. For example, some sections might be one height for one product but then a completely different height for other products. So I need it to be able to dynamically size each section and I also need to be able to animate some size changes (for example, the section where it adds a row to the table and then removes it, that needs to animate and make the whole section larger in an animated fashion).

Also, I would like each section to be modular and to not end up having a giant view controller that manages everything. I would like each section to essentially be self contained. I just pass data to that section and then it handles everything related to layout and interaction. But again, the real issue is getting those views to be able to resize and to have that update in the parent view (stack view currently).

But I am really new to iOS development, and while I have been trying to learn as fast as I can, I am still not sure if the way that I am doing this currently (the scroll view with the stack view inside it) is the best approach or if there are better approaches. I tried this initially in a table view with static cells where each row was a different section. But then getting the child view controllers to resize the row in the parent table view was not working that well. Since then I have also changed from making each section be a separate view controller and just have each section be a view (rather than view controller) to make resizing hopefully easier, but I am still running into issues. I have also considered collection views, but I also need to be able to support iOS 12 (or I could drop iOS 12 support if I really need to and just support iOS 13+).

But to restate, my overall goals are to have some way to layout this interface which consists of different views that each handle different data. I would like each view to be able to resize and for that to be able to be smooth. And I would like each section of the interface to be modular so as to avoid one large view controller.

## Update 2

After following the suggestion to wrap the table view in a UIView and then set the two bottom constraints with different priorities, this is what I am getting. I also get this effect anytime I try to animate things like the height constraint of views. I think this is because the overall view here is contained inside a stack view, so I think the stack view is doing something when its arranged subview changes size.

The picture here shows both expanding the table view and collapsing it. When it is collapsed it has three rows visible and when it is expanded it has five rows.

The yellow and blue views are representative of other views on the page. They are not part of this view and neither is the stack view they are contained within. They are just other parts of the page included here to show this issue. All the views here are contained in a stack view and I think that is what is causing the issue with the animation, but I am not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: A better work around is using UICollectionView to customize your expandable table, while  expanding just call `reloadSections(_:with:)` to reload specific section.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to "expand/collapse'. Your animated image appears to show table rows *moving* ... are you just trying to "reveal" an already populated table view?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry for the quality of the gif, it is way too fast. But what is happening is that we start out with 3 rows and then when I expand the table, the table seems to have its `frame.height` set before adding any rows and then it adds the rows. But this causes the rest of the sections below this table section to "jump" down rather than smoothly animate. I tried also having the table fully populated and then adding a height constraint on the table, but that also caused jumping because of the stack view this is wrapped in. Is there a better way to lay out interfaces than using a stack view?

Comment: @pqteru Do you mean to use a UICollectionView to handle the layout of the app? I have tried using a UITableView with static cells and I tried using a stack view so far. Both of them cause me issues when I need to resize one of the sections (it could be either a UIViewController subclass or a UIView subclass). But I need to be able to support dynamically expanding and collapsing items within these sections, so the sections need to be able to grow and shrink height. I also am trying to support iOS 12+, but I could drop that and support iOS 13+ if necessary. What kind of layout do you recommend?

Comment: @DonMag Or do you see anything wrong with my code? When I add all rows to the table view and then just set the height of the table via a constraint and then animate that, it works if I have the containing view set to a very large height (for this section, I have a UIView and inside it I have a label and a table, as is shown in the code) so that it does not have to expand. But if the table view has to stretch the containing view, that is when it stops working correctly. I am just trying to get the section to be autosized and for it to be able to smoothly expand and collapse the table as needed.

Comment: @ashipma - it's still not clear what you want to do... You say your tableView is in a stackView... are you trying to display more/fewer rows in the table? Or do you want, for example, the first 3 rows always visible, and show/hide the remaining rows?

Comment: @DonMag This section of the page shows details about a product, such as in the screenshots it is showing details about a car. There can be a lot of details, so to prevent this section from taking up too much of the page, I am wanting to have a button to toggle between the full table view (showing all the rows) or a shortened table view (showing only maybe 3 rows). So the functionality should be: if <= 3 rows, do not show the button. If > 3 rows show the button. If the button is clicked, then show all the rows. If the button is clicked again, only show three rows. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ashipma - is there a reason you don't use a single tableView (with multiple sections if needed)?

Comment: @DonMag I am fairly new to iOS development, so I am still trying to figure things out, but my goal is to design this in such a way that each section is in its own view or view controller and then there is just some layout view controller that takes these separate views and displays them. I am trying to avoid having everything in one giant view controller if possible. And each section has really different content (some sections have a table view, some have a collection view, some have expandable table rows that contain a collection view, whereas others contain page controllers or just labels.

Comment: @DonMag (continued) But my goal is to have something modular where I can just add a new view or view controller to it and that view controller is implemented elsewhere. I also want each view controller to be able to grow or shrink as needed (in an animated fashion). One issue I faced when starting this project was that I wasn't sure how to go about this, whether I should use a table view or a collection view or a stack view or just add each view controller or view directly to a scroll view and use AutoLayout, or if there was yet another way of handling this. What approach do you recommend?

Comment: @DonMag I added a section to the question titled `Update - a high level overview of what I am trying to do`. You may have seen this on a previous question and it is similar, but I have updated it a bit with my overall goals. But I am not sure what the best approach to laying this content out is, so if the way I am doing it now is wrong, I can change it. But thank you again for everything. I really appreciate your help with all my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have a bunch of questions here - but to address specifically the issue with trying to expand/collapse your table view...

I think you'll be fighting a losing battle with this approach. By trying to use an "auto-sizing" table view, you're counter-acting much of a table view's behaviors/ And, since you are not getting the benefit of memory management with reusable cells, you're probably better off formatting your "spec list" with a vertical stack view.

In either case, to create a collapse / expand animation with a "reveal / hide" effect, you may want to embed the tableView or stackView in a "container" view, and then toggle constraint priorities for the height (the bottom) of the container.

Here is a quick example...

- create a "container" `UIView`
- add a vertical stack view to the container
- add labels to the stack view
- add a red `UIView` to place above the container
- add a blue `UIView` to place below the container
- define constraints for the height of the container

On each tap, the container will expand / collapse to reveal / hide the labels.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *collapsedConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *expandedConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIStackView *labelsStackView = [UIStackView new];
    labelsStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    labelsStackView.spacing = 4;
    
    // let's add 12 labels to the stack view (12 "rows")
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        UILabel *v = [UILabel new];
        v.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %d", i];
        [labelsStackView addArrangedSubview:v];
    }
    
    // add a view to show above the stack view
    UIView *redView = [UIView new];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
    // add a view to show below the stack view
    UIView *blueView = [UIView new];
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // add a "container" view for the stack view
    UIView *cView = [UIView new];
    
    // clip the container's subviews
    cView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    
    for (UIView *v in @[redView, cView, blueView]) {
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:v];
    }
    
    // add the stackView to the container
    labelsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [cView addSubview:labelsStackView];
    
    // constraints
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    
    // when expanded, we'll use the full height of the stack view
    _expandedConstraint = [cView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:labelsStackView.bottomAnchor];
    
    // when collapsed, we'll use the bottom of the 3rd label in the stack view
    UILabel *v = labelsStackView.arrangedSubviews[2];
    _collapsedConstraint = [cView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v.bottomAnchor];
    
    // start collapsed
    _expandedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
    _collapsedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        // redView Top / Leading / Trailing / Height=120
        [redView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [redView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [redView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [redView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:120.0],
        
        // container Top==redView.bottom / Leading / Trailing / no height
        [cView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:redView.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
        [cView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [cView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        
        // blueView Top==stackView.bottom / Leading / Trailing / Height=160
        [blueView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cView.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
        [blueView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [blueView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [blueView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:160.0],
        
        // stackView Top / Leading / Trailing
        [labelsStackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cView.topAnchor],
        [labelsStackView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cView.leadingAnchor],
        [labelsStackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cView.trailingAnchor],

        _expandedConstraint,
        _collapsedConstraint,
        
    ]];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // toggle priority between expanded / collapsed constraints
    if (_expandedConstraint.priority == UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh) {
        _expandedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
        _collapsedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    } else {
        _collapsedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
        _expandedConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    }
    // animate the change
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
    
}

@end
```

You *may* be able to implement that with your "auto-sizing" table view, but again, since you're not using the "normal" table view behaviors (scrolling, reusable cells, etc), this might be a better approach.

Hopefully, it can also give you some insight to sizing other views in your layout - particularly if you want to animate them in or out of view.

**Edit** - added a more complex example here: https://github.com/DonMag/Scratch2021

It uses a vertical stack view in a vertical scroll view as the "main view" UI, adding child view controllers as "components" in the stack view.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help here. I will try this out. But do you have any suggestions about whether the way I am laying all this out overall (using the stack view) is correct or if there is a better way? You mentioned the memory benefits I am losing out on by not using the table in the correct manner. If you had to lay out a page like this (think of this like a product page on a retail website where they have pictures, descriptions, reviews, ...), how would you do it? I would like it to be composed of smaller views, like this, so I can keep each view single focused and manageable. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion to wrap the tableview in a UIView and then add the collapsed and expanded bottom constraints on it and it works, but when animating, the parent stack view isn't animating correctly. I have had this issue previously and was unable to solve it. The overall view defined by this class is added as an arranged subview of a parent stack view that is used to layout all the sections of the page. I added an update to the question titled **Update 2** and that has a gif showing the animation. Do you know if there is some setting in the stack view that might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: @ashipma - without seeing your full attempt, tough to say. I put up a more complex example that is closer to your UI and approach: https://github.com/DonMag/Scratch2021

Comment: Thank you so very much for putting all this together and taking this much time and effort to do this. I really appreciate your help. And again, you have solved my problem. I added the traversal to the root view (or in this case I could just stop at the parent stack view I suppose) and that fixed everything. I am not totally sure how a stack view works internally, but I guess if we animate anything that changes the height of an arranged subview, then we need to layout the entire stack view. I was previously just laying out the subview and that was not working. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey @DonMag - I just posted a question that is sort of similar to this (it is about animation again for this same project). This time I have a section with a table view that has expandable sections. Each section contains one row which is a collection view. But the animation is kind of weird. You definitely do not need to look at it if you do not want to, but I would really appreciate any insights you might have or any suggestions for alternative solutions to this. Thank you so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541899/uitableview-smooth-expand-and-collapse-showing-a-uicollectionview